# Excel - can not find text in array and return value from cell below

Tags: indexing, excel-formula, match, vlookup

Hello to all Excel masters here :-)

I'm trying to find a text and return a value from cell below, but Match always returns `#N/A`.

I'm on sheet "Skript01" in cell F2
I want to put there value from sheet "Prehled testu" cell L6.
I need this to be dynamically found everytime, even when rows or columns changes, so I can not use any exact row or column number.

There is a formula in "Skript01" in cell F2, which finds name of a sheet, then find it on sheet "Prehled testu" and then returs value from column 12. If there is some error, it returns 0.

```
=IF(ISERR(INDEX('Prehled testu'!A:N;MATCH(MID(CELL("filename";A1);FIND("]";CELL("filename";A1))+1;255);'Prehled testu'!A:A;0);12));0;INDEX('Prehled testu'!A:N;MATCH(MID(CELL("filename";A1);FIND("]";CELL("filename";A1))+1;255);'Prehled testu'!A:A;0);12))
```

Please can you help me to dynamically decide column number of "% otestováno" (now column 12) and put it together with my formula? I will then copy it to other sheets (Skript02, 03...) and it must work - find the right value adjacent to chosen sheet.

Link to file:
http://r-man.cz/Download/02%20Random/TeT_sablona.zip

Thank You.

Comment: I'm not sure how many people are going to risk downloading a zip file from a website they've never seen before just to help debug your code... :¬/  Can you provide screenshots of the minimum data needed to understand the issue?

Comment: The server is my own, it is 100% safe. But I understand what do You mean. It's not that easy to say it by screenshot - that's why I uploaded my worksheet.

Comment: http://r-man.cz/Download/02%20Random/TeT_sablona_Screenshot01.JPG and http://r-man.cz/Download/02%20Random/TeT_sablona_Screenshot02.JPG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on Chronocidals answer:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Prehled testu'!A:N;MATCH(MID(CELL("filename";A1);FIND("]";CELL("filename";A1))+1;255);'Prehled testu'!A:A;0);MATCH("% otestováno";INDIRECT((CONCATENATE("'Prehled testu'!";(MATCH(C2;'Prehled testu'!A:A;0)-1);":";(MATCH(C2;'Prehled testu'!A:A;0)-1))));0));0)
```

This was way harder than I expected but it should work as you want it to. Only requirement that this formula has is that "Název" of table in Script sheets should match the title of the tables in the "Prehled testu" sheet.

Comment: Is there a possibility to avoid the "A5:Z5" and search for the cell instead? Something like "A:Z" , but it do not work :-(

Comment: I'd use "5:5" if you're absolutely positive that the first table always starts on the row 5. Atm I'm trying to find a way to make this work even if tables have different number of columns and don't start on row 5.

Comment: "way to make this work even if tables have different number of columns and don't start on row 5" - yes, that's what i need and what I'm looking for a whole day. I will use this formula in other workbooks with same principle, but different table structures.

Comment: Ok I think I'm almost done, i got one more question. If you got "Script01" in the table on the first sheet, is Script01 going to be anywhere on the "Script01" Sheet or not ?

Comment: Test OK - Thank You so much for help! Now I have to force users to follow the requirements all the time (=impossible task) :-)

Comment: Ok if you are satisfied with my answer please select it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a
   [difference](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/is-functions-0f2d7971-6019-40a0-a171-f2d869135665)
   between `ISERR` and `ISERROR` - that difference is that `ISERR(#NA)`
   = `FALSE`, but `ISERROR(#NA)` = `TRUE`
2. You can greatly simplify your code using
   [`IFERROR`](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/iferror-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611):
   `IFERROR(A,B)` is the same as writing `IF(ISERROR(A),B,A)`

Giving:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Prehled testu'!A:N;MATCH(MID(CELL("filename";A1);FIND("]";CELL("filename";A1))+1;255);'Prehled testu'!A:A;0);12);0)
```

Comment: OK, thanks. But that's not the issue I'm trying to solve here.

Comment: It *does* mean that you should be getting `0` instead of `#NA` on an error though.  This will try to match the current worksheet name against the column.  (Incidentally, the `A1` reference is not needed in the `CELL` formula: `CELL("filename")` will work fine)

Comment: (Well, I say "work fine" - it will use the ActiveCell, so only works when the worksheet you is selected)